# How to Create Seed Node for Cryptonote Fork

Tags: cryptonote

I have fork Cryptonote and made .rawiumd, and recompiled it successfully on Google Cloud computing.
I have created another 2 instances in google cloud computing.
I have modified CryptoNoteConfig.h file and mentioned both instances IP address at port 17236.
I have installed all dependencies too.
When I run ./rawiumd it says, continouing without seed node, cannot connect.
Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

Make the build again after adding below changes in **src/CryptoNoteConfig.h**

Add IP addresses of your seed nodes.

Example:

```
const std::initializer_list<const char*> SEED_NODES = {
  "192.168.0.11:17236",
  "192.168.0.12:17236",
};
```

**OR**

create one file **coin.conf** in **cryptonote/build/release/** and add below lines

```
seed-node=192.168.0.11:8080
seed-node=192.168.0.12:8080
```

and start the node with below command

```
$ ./yourcoind --config-file coin.conf
```

**source :**

https://cryptonotestarter.org/inner.html

http://forknote.net/guides/setup-private-blockchain/

Comment: both projects seems to be defunct! any idea where is the most up to date fork?